# PHP setcookie() for domain but NOT subdomains

Tags: php, cookies, subdomain

Is there any way to set a cookie that is *not* readable on subdomains? In other words, have the cookie available on `domain.com`, but **not** `www.domain.com` or `xyz.domain.com`.

```
//this is what i'm "intending"...
setcookie($name,$value,$expires,'/','domain.com');
//however, this is how it behaves:
setcookie($name,$value,$expires,'/','.domain.com');
```

The reasoning: I'm setting up a static CDN on a subdomain and don't want the user session cookies going back and forth for every image, css file, js file, etc.

...do I have to fall back to using `www.domain.com` for my site? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: Setting the domain to `null` is the only correct thing to do here. Otherwise, you might find [`$cookie->setDomain($domain)`](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie/blob/004cde69ec840e65c15275e09b92ecb1da06f357/src/Cookie.php#L117) helpful, as found in [this standalone library](https://github.com/delight-im/PHP-Cookie).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Apparently, having a cookie on "domain.com" that will match "*.domain.com" is expected behaviour.

For instance : [PERSISTENT CLIENT STATE HTTP COOKIES](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) state *(some emphasis mine)* :

> **`domain=DOMAIN_NAME`**
>
> When searching the cookie list for
>   valid cookies, a comparison of the
>   domain attributes of the cookie is
>   made with the Internet domain name of
>   the host from which the URL will be
>   fetched. ... 
> "Tail matching" means
>   that domain attribute is matched
>   against the tail of the fully
>   qualified domain name of the host. **A
>   domain attribute of "acme.com" would
>   match host names "anvil.acme.com" as
>   well as "shipping.crate.acme.com"**.
>
> Only hosts within the specified domain
>   can set a cookie for a domain and
>   domains must have **at least two (2)
>   or three (3) periods** in them to
>   prevent domains of the form: ".com",
>   ".edu", and "va.us". Any domain that
>   fails within one of the seven special
>   top level domains listed below only
>   require two periods. Any other domain
>   requires at least three. The seven
>   special top level domains are: "COM",
>   "EDU", "NET", "ORG", "GOV", "MIL", and
>   "INT".

So, you'll either have to :

- use "`www.domain.com`" for your site
- or use a totally different domain name for your static content (like "`.anotherdomain.com`")

  - for instance, this is what is done on stackoverflow : static content is served from sstatic.net

Comment: Nice explanation, +1 here as well.

Comment: Wow, great info. I didn't run across that when digging around. Thanks man. I guess this answers my question... www.domain.com it is.

Comment: You're welcome :-) Have fun ! (and, if using www.domain.com for your website and cookies, don't forget to make sure that "domain.com", when used to access your site, redirects to "www.domain.com" -- do not depending on the browser to do that automatically : it doesn't always work -- doesn't work behind a proxy, sometimes, for instance (that's the case where I work, and it's a pain))

Answer (score 6):

this is the reason why quite a few sites (including this one) register a dedicated domain for use as a CDN.

Answer (score 2):

Of cource you can! That's what most websites do. Even the built-in php function `session_start()` does that. and its Set-Cookie http response header looks just as simple as this:

```
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=fe26eaac143ef75ffcbc91bbe5780d0d; path=/
```

According to [RFC 6265, section 4.1.2.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.2.3), the last statement in the paragraph:

> If the server omits the Domain attribute, the user
> agent will return the cookie ***only*** to the origin server.

So, all you have to do is to omit the domain attribute while setting the cookie from your `domain.com`

```
setcookie($name,$value,$expires,'/','');
```

For further confirmation, I tested it myself, and I can assure you, cookies aren't accessible from subdomains when you set 'em while omitting the domain attribute.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible as the cookie domain is [tail matched](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html) against the domain name. You will have to go with www.