# How to set cookies for specific sub domain in php?

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, dns, subdomain

Example : `http://devlocal.com`, `http://ca.devlocal.com` and `http://pa.devlocal.com`. I need to set cookie only for `devlocal.com` and `ca.devlocal.com`.

```
setcookie("token", $token, time()+60*60*24*1, "/", "");// for devlocal.com
setcookie("token", $token, time()+60*60*24*2, "/", "ca.devlocal.com");//for ca.devlocal.com
```

I am setting cookies from `devlocal.com`

I am using laravel so please suggest if laravel have better solution.

Can you suggest how to set and get laravel cookie without encryption because token should be exact check to token provider in my case it is `jwt`

Comment: by default laravel will set the cookie for the domain specified in session.php as domain key..so if you want specific cookies to be set for specific domain before setting cookie dynamically modify the value of domain key...

Comment: _“I need to set cookie only for devlocal.com and ca.devlocal.com”_ - that is not really possible. A cookie you set for `devlocal.com` automatically becomes valid for all subdomains.

Comment: can you suggest how to set and get laravel cookie without encryption because token should be exact check to token provider in my case it is `jwt`

Comment: @CBroe nice point.. indeed a cookie set for a specific domain will be available for all its subdomains..here is quick google i found..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417963/php-setcookie-for-domain-but-not-subdomains

Comment: You can checkout this link https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/15558410de2a394373ac